# Sound plays on headphones and speakers with Lenovo ThinkPad L512  + Ubuntu 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, audio, thinkpad

The only thing really missing from this install is this issue with the sound. I've searched all over the forums and i found one thing where you get the model and codecs and write them to a file, however, I can't seem to find what my "model" is because none of the postings have anything about Lenovo laptops. Here is the command they all asked for:
Code:

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC269
Codec: Intel G45 DEVIBX
```

With that info, how do I get the model, and how do I get my speakers to stop playing when headphones are plugged in. Also, I don't have any software installed like pulse audio either, so it's not that.

Thanks so much to whoever can answer this...

The Ubuntu forums are nearly useless... ive never gotten a correct answer back on that site.

Comment: This is a good question, although I do not have a thinkpad my lenovo workstation at work does the same thing and I have to find a proper audible level so the headphones are loud enough but speakesr are not too loud to distract everyone else.

Comment: Does your headphones use a phono-jack or usb? It makes a _HUGE_ difference.

Answer (score 0):

Linux on a ThinkPad?  The first port of call should be the [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/).

I'm guessing that you have an Intel powered Edge, from those specs.

Apparently, you need to add the line...

```
options snd-hda-intel model="olpc-xo-1_5"
```

to the end of `/etc/modprobe.conf/alsa-base.conf`

[See here.](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:Edge_13%22)

Comment: I have an L512, and that didn't seem to work, i think you also have a typo. I believe you meant modprobe.d? I added your line at the very bottom tho via sudo gedit -> saved -> reboot and went to rdio.com and played music with headphones in and it still is coming from the speakers :'(

Comment: I just pasted what was on the page I linked to at the bottom.

Comment: do you have any other ideas? If I use pulse audio it works fine

Answer (score -2):

## ALC269 accepts following "model" options:

```
basic       Basic preset
quanta  Quanta FL1
laptop-amic Laptops with analog-mic input
laptop-dmic Laptops with digital-mic input
fujitsu FSC Amilo
lifebook    Fujitsu Lifebook S6420
auto        auto-config reading BIOS (default)
```